# Splitting at Space Between Letter and Digit

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having the worst time with this simple regex.

Example input:

```
Cleveland Indians 5, Boston Redsox 4
```

I'm trying to split at the `,` and the space between the letter and number

Example output:

```
Cleveland Indians
5
Boston Redsox
4
```

Here is what I have so far, but it's including the number still.

```
/,|\s[0-9]/
```

Comment: How about splitting on `,` then on space? The last elements will be the number and the first X will be the name of the team. That or work from the last index of the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string = "Cleveland Indians 5, Boston Redsox 4"
string.split /,\s*|\s(?=\d)/
# => ["Cleveland Indians", "5", "Boston Redsox", "4"]
```

`\s(?=\d)`: a space followed by a digit using [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. Could you explain the second part of the regex?

Answer (score 1):

If you divide it into two splits -- one at the comma + space, then one to separate the team name from the score -- it might be a bit clearer, especially if you have to add more options like a space *before* the comma too (real-world data gets messy!):

```
scores = "Cleveland Indians 5, Boston Redsox 4"
scores.split(/,\s*/).map{|score| score.split(/\s+(?=\d)/)}
 => [["Cleveland Indians", "5"], ["Boston Redsox", "4"]]
```

The resulting list of lists is a more meaningful grouping, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Cleveland Indians 5, Boston Redsox 4".split(/\s*(\d+)(?:,\s+|\z)/)
# => ["Cleveland Indians", "5", "Boston Redsox", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
str = "Cleveland Indians 15, Boston Red Sox 4"
phrases = str.split(", ")

phrases.each do |phrase|
  *team_names, score = phrase.split(" ")
  puts team_names.join " "
  puts score
end


--output:--
Cleveland Indians
15
Boston Red Sox
4
```

.

2)

```
str = "Cleveland Indians 15, Boston Red Sox 4"

pieces = str.split(/
    \s*       #A space 0 or more times
    (\d+)     #A digit 1 or more times, include match with results
    [,\s]*    #A comma or space, 0 or more times
/x)           

puts pieces



--output:--
Cleveland Indians
15
Boston Red Sox
4
```

The first split is on " 15, " and the second split is on " 4" -- with the score included in the results.

.

3)

```
str = "Cleveland Indians 15, Boston Red Sox 4"

str.scan(/
    (
      \w      #Begin with a word character
      \D+     #followed by not a digit, 1 or more times
    )
    [ ]       #followed by a space
    (\d+)     #followed by a digit, one or more times
/x) {|capture_groups| puts capture_groups}


--output:--
Cleveland Indians
15
Boston Red Sox
4
```